# A way to convert a filtered KStream from Kafka into an array in Java

Tags: java, loops, filter, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Is there a way to convert a filtered KStream into an array just as java streams-api has the `toArray()`-method.

I tried by:

```
builder.filter().foreach({ list.add(element);});
```

That did not work at all and I always get an empty array while printing the content.

Is it possible or should I use something else like a K-Table or KSQLDB?

Comment: Where are you actually printing anything? I assume you're only doing it once?

Comment: yes further in the course of the program

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it's possible, but the foreach action happens in a separate thread than any print outside of it, and that thread will keep running... In other words, if you print the list immediately after the add method within the foreach, then it won't be empty

You'd need to terminate the stream topology and wait for it somehow to get the final list (at which point it would make more sense to use a plain Consumer that you could actually pause/stop polling)

Generally, only use a KTable / KSQL if you want to dedupe the record keys

Comment: hmm difficult.  I just wanted to build a rest API for various searches without creating a topic for every little thing.  Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @platofan23 I said nothing about topic management or searching... If you just want a consumer from a REST API, then you can look how the existing Kafka REST Proxy works. It does not use Kafka Streams. Even if you used a KTable, then any REST call to get its data would return data _at that moment_, and multiple calls could return different datasets, depending on what has been consumed. But overall, it is not suggested to combine a Kafka consumer with a blocking request-response model.